# OpenCL - local_work_size influence nothing

Tags: opencl

I am running openCL program with this code:

```
CL_CHECK( clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(this->commands, this->kernel, 
                    settings.dimCount, NULL, settings.globalWorkSize, settings.localWorkSize, 
                    0, NULL, NULL) );
```

where

```
settings.dimCount = 3
settings.globalWorkSize = {100, 1, 1}
settings.localWorkSize = {10, 1, 1}
```

But my output data that are given by get_global_id(0) is always in range <0, 100> and never more. Why ? I expected to get range <0, 1000>

My Kernel

```
__kernel void main(                                              
   __global float* output)                                           
{                                                                      

   //int i = get_local_id(0) + get_local_size(0) * get_group_id(0); //should be same as get_global_id  
   int i = get_global_id(0);                                                   
   output[i] = i;                              
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The global work size is the total number of items that will be processed. If it's 100, you'll have 100 items, no more.

The local work size is the number of items allocated to each work group. The total number of work groups is then determined by dividing one by the other - in your case, you will have 10 work groups, each processing 10 work items.

Comment: Ok.. so If i want to process 100 000 indices, I need to have max number of global_work_sizes and then loop inside each kernel ? So for example 10, 10, 10 (1000) and inside kernel loop for i = 0 to 100 ?

Comment: @MartinPerry if you want to process 100,000 indices, you should set the global work size to be 100,000 (or more accurately, you need the multiplication of the 3 global work size dimensions to be 100,000).

Comment: So settings up local size only affects global size cohherency ? Eg. I am telling that I want to run some number of threads on single multiprocessor ?

Comment: @MartinPerry how many work items run on each thread or in each processor is implementation-defined. Work group size does have semantic impact, though: in particular all the items in the same work group share the same `local` memory space, and can be synchronized with the use of barriers. If you have no semantic need for a specific work group size, it's best to leave it as `NULL` and let the implementation decide.

Answer (score 0):

When you call:

```
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(this->commands, this->kernel, 
                    settings.dimCount, NULL, settings.globalWorkSize, settings.localWorkSize, 
                    0, NULL, NULL)
```

The Global and Local Work sizes are exactly what you set them to be.

In your case,

```
settings.globalWorkSize = {100, 1, 1}
settings.localWorkSize = {10, 1, 1}
```

Why should you expect the values to be any different?

Try a few experiments: change the values and rerun your code.

Comment: I was assuming similar behavior like DirectCompute, where in this case 100 groups and each with 10 thread will be executed => total 1000 threads

Comment: @MartinPerry In fact it is easyer this way. You only need 2 values, local and global. Why sohuld you need to multiple or care about how many packets will be run?